# Static into OSPF Redistribution

Tags: networking, cisco, routing, static-routes, ospf

I am trying to create static routes which are redistributed as E1 Type 5 External OSPF LSAs. If I check the routing tables on my other connected routers, these redistributed routes show up properly. However, the routes appear as static routes on the router where I created them. Is there any way to have this router where I created the static routes see them as E1 Type 5 External OSPF LSAs as well?

Comment: How would the originator of the route also be a receiver? This request doesn't make sense at all?

Comment: I was curious if there was any way to trick the originator into thinking it is also one of the receivers. This may sound weird, but I want to see if its possible.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is setting up a VRF and having it peer to itself in that VRF so that you have this cute little island onboard to show you what's being exported into your routing topologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't do that.  A router can only have one route in the routing table per exact prefix.  For instance, it's impossible to have both an EIGRP and an OSPF route installed in the routing table.  Administrative Distance (lowest) determines which route is used.

Additionally, even if you did force the router with the static route to instead use the OSPF route (by AD manipulation or some other black magic), the router would then stop originating the T5 LSA.

This is what would happen.

- you add static routes on the local router, which are installed into
  the routing table
- the router redistributes those routes into OSPF as T5 LSA
- through some unknown hackery, you convince the router to use the T5 LSAs instead of the static route
- the router now withdraws the T5 LSA, as it no longer has the source static route
- ???

**What are you trying to accomplish with this?**  Why would you want the router to use the T5 LSA instead of the locally-configured static route?

Do note that even though the router will use the static route in the routing table, it still knows about the T5 LSA in its OSPF LSA database.

```
show ip ospf database external <prefix>
```

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my understanding. As far as what I was trying to accomplish goes...I was looking to replicate a specific scenario for the sake of comparing some data.